# Windows 7: Taking advantage of auto-elevation to elevate my own process?

Tags: windows, windows-7, uac, elevation, rootkit

From a July 2009 Technet article entitled [Inside Windows 7 User Account Control](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.uac.aspx), **Mark Russinovish** describes that it's possible for an application running as standard user to silently elevate and gain administrative rights:

> ...it's possible for third-party
>   software running in a PA (Protected Administrator) account with
>   standard user rights to take advantage
>   of auto-elevation to gain
>   administrative rights. For example,
>   the software can use the
>   [WriteProcessMemory API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674.aspx) to inject code into *Explorer* and the
>   [CreateRemoteThread API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682437(VS.85).aspx) to execute that code, a technique called *DLL
>   injection*. Since the code is executing
>   in Explorer, which is a Windows
>   executable, it can leverage the COM
>   objects that auto-elevate, like the
>   Copy/Move/Rename/Delete/Link Object,
>   to modify system registry keys or
>   directories and give the software
>   administrative rights.

He goes on to mention that malware will never do this, because it's too hard:

> ...these steps require
>   deliberate intent, aren't trivial...

and finally

> ...malware could gain administrative
>   rights using the same techniques.

So i'm curious to see an actual implementation.

---

i would have thought **[PROCESS_VM_WRITE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684880.aspx)** would be a right not given to standard users.

**Note:** i would never actually do anything bad myself, as is true for every other developer in the world.

Comment: Malware's never been something to balk at things being too hard :)

Comment: i know. i was also hoping for further discussion here on that point.

Comment: The guys that write malware have no deadlines, do not have to worry about budgets and do not have to write nicely formatted code that does not break things :).

In my opinion, if they want to do something, they will find a way to do it, no matter how difficult.

Comment: Please don't do this.  It will only make the Windows team very unhappy when they are forced to figure out how to keep your application working in the future.

This kind of technique is best left to malware - if your application requires elevation to work correctly, there are other techniques to avoid the elevation prompt that ARE supported (for instance you can isolate the code that requires elevation into a service and use RPC to communicate with the service).

Comment: @Larry: i have no actual intention of using this hole to elevate anything. i'm hoping that by getting it out there, with malware taking advantage of it to gain complete control of systems, Microsoft will address the issue.  (p.s. more blogs please)

Comment: The behavior isn't going to be changed, the system is working as designed.  Asking for sample code won't help.

Comment: With enough malicious software taking advantage of it, i hope it will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long Zheng, over at [istartedsomething.com](http://istartedsomething.com) has a few posts about autoelevating an application. He's not the author of the source code, but he links to the person that made the proof-of-concept.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20090613/windows-7-uac-code-injection-vulnerability-video-demonstration-source-code-released/).

Answer (score 1):

are you talking about using process injection? or elevating the privileges?'

If you want to see a code sample of a process injection this thread has some samples:
http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/index.php?showtopic=23539&hl=bypassing+firewall

Comment: Those guys have an interesting way of communicating... And as for bypassing the UAC: Microsoft puts out a bounty of up to $ 100.000 for a functioning exploit. So you can guess it's both hard to do and you would want to give it to Microsoft instead of posting it on a hacker's forum.